# Dependency injection (@Inject and @PersistenceContext) failing for stateless bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, dependency-injection, cdi

```
Env :

Wildfly 8.2.0 / Wildfly 9.0.1
```

My application structure is as follows

Servlet -> MyStateless1 -> MyStateless2 -> entity manager api

As long as both `MyStateless1` and `MyStateless2` are non EJBs, it is working flawlessly with pure CDI injection i.e. able to query DB successfully. Once I mark `MyStateless1` as `@Stateless`, even though the `@Inject` of EJB `MyStateless1` in servlet works fine, the injection inside `MyStateless1` itself doesn't work. Note that both `@Inject` and `@PersistenceContext` fails to inject the concerned resources.

Here is the code

```
@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject private MyStateless1 stateless1;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                         HttpServletResponse response) {
      stateless1.businessMethod();
      response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }
}
```

First level Bean

```
//@Stateless
public class MyStateless1 {
    @Inject private MyStateless2 stateless2;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "cdi-rest")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public MyStateless1() {
      System.out.println("MyStateless1() constructed");
    }

    public final void businessMethod() {
      if (entityManager == null ) { System.out.println(" +++++ Entity Manager is null"); }
      if (stateless2 == null ) { System.out.println(" ===== stateless2 is null"); } else { stateless2.finder(); }
    }
}
```

Second level bean

```
public class MyStateless2 {

  public MyStateless2() {
    System.out.println("MyStateless2() constructed ");
  }

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "cdi-rest")
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public final List<MyEntity> finder() {
    TypedQuery<MyEntity> query = entityManager.createQuery("select o from MyEntity o", MyEntity.class);
    return query.getResultList();
  }
}
```

The moment i uncomment the `@Stateless` in first level bean, injection inside `MyStsteless2` doesnt work i.e. both `@Inject` and `@PersistenceContext`

The folder structure is as follows

```
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── rakesh
│   │   │           ├── model
│   │   │           │   └── MyEntity.java
│   │   │           ├── persistence
│   │   │           │   └── MyStateless2.java
│   │   │           ├── service
│   │   │           │   └── MyStateless1.java
│   │   │           └── servlet
│   │   │               └── MyServlet.java
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │       └── persistence.xml
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       └── WEB-INF
│   │           ├── beans.xml
│   │           └── web.xml
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       └── resources
```

What i had tried:

- Above code is one WAR file but i also created a WAR with Stateless
  and JPA code separated into a jar file. Same problem.
- Annotated `MyStateless1` with both `@Stateless` and `@LocalBean` / `@Local`.
  Same problem
- Tried in both wildfly versions i.e. 8.2.0 and 9.0.1. Same problem

Any thoughts/help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Rakesh

Comment: What happens when you remove the final modifier from your methods?

Comment: Wow. That was stupid of me. The EIB spec clearly says that the business methods must not be final or static. Thanks @JBNizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JBNizet; it was 'final' modifier in methods that caused the issue.